# Issue when using Scrollview inside Dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I am inflating a layout inside a dialog, which consist of a scrollview but the layout is not scrolling. I have referred so many questions from stackoverflow but then also its not working. My layout.xml is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ScrollView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@color/White"
       >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Update available"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/upgrade_msg"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.02"
            android:src="@drawable/updateimg2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_upgrade"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_forget_pwd"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/White"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Upgrade Now"
            android:textColor="@color/Black" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/line_y_h" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_remind"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_forget_pwd"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/White"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Remind Me Later"
            android:textColor="@color/Blue" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/line_y_h" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

- Dialog code

  ```
    public void show_Alert_version_custom(String str, final String url,
              final String exitStatus)// use for
      {
          final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Splash.this);
          dialog.setContentView(R.layout.version_update);
          dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.alert_title));
          Button dialogButton2 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_remind);
          dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_upgrade);
          ImageView viewLine = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);


          // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
          dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {}
          });

          // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
          dialogButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {}
          });

          dialog.show();
      }
  ```

Comment: can you post your dialoge code??

Comment: its better to use another xml file...don`t go for such big dialog.

Comment: You will have to use the static height of scrollview.

Comment: Generally `ScrollView` scroll when there is some more content. Though use this code will scroll it. `scrollview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     try {
      v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
     } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO: handle exception
     }

     return false;
    }
   });`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

android:fillViewport="true" in ScrollView solved my problem. Now its scrolling even inside dialog.

Comment: helpful for me. I was stuck with this issue in my code.

Comment: Just to clarify, you place that code inside Scrollview tag like this: `<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:fillViewport="true"  

android:layout_margin="5dp" 
android:background="@color/White" >`

Comment: @GianGomen yes i did it like you saying

Answer (score 1):

You can use simply below code on ScollView. it's working fine.

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```